# A simple proof of Poincaré's index theorem on surfaces, that does not use Gauss-Bonnet

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am self-studying differential geometry of curves and surfaces, primarily from do Carmo's book. As an application of Gauss-Bonnet (GB), he proves Poincaré's index theorem (p.283). I think I have a modification of his argument that completely avoids the use of Gaussian curvature and of GB, and so it is much simpler conceptually. After looking at other books (Pressley's, Tapp's and others) I see that all proofs use GB, which makes me wonder if my argument is correct. I would greatly appreciate any comments on it. Here it is:

Let $S$ be the surface, $v$ be the smooth vector field defined on it. Let $V(p):= \frac{v(p)}{\|v(p)\|}$ for any $p\in S$ that is not singular. Do Carmo states (without proof) the existence of the following triangulation:

> There exists a triangulation of $S$ such that
>
> 1. Every triangle $T$ is contained in some coordinate neighborhood.
> 2. Every $T$ contains at most one singular point.
> 3. The boundary of every $T$ contains no singular points and is positively oriented.
> 4. Adjacent triangles determine opposite orientations in the common
>    edge.

Now, fix a triangle $T$ and a parametrization $\sigma : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S$ such that $T\subseteq \sigma(U)$. Consider unit-speed parametrizations of the three edges of $T$, i.e. $\ \gamma_1:[t_0,t_1] \rightarrow S,\ \gamma_2:[t_1,t_2] \rightarrow S,\ \gamma_3:[t_2,t_3] \rightarrow S$. Let $\gamma:[t_0,t_3]$ be their concatention (which is piecewise smooth, simple, closed parametrization of the boundary of $T$). Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \in [-\pi,\pi]$ be the external angles of $\gamma$ as in the picture:

[image]

For convenience, we define $\gamma'(t_1):=\gamma_2'(t_1),\ \gamma'(t_2):=\gamma_3'(t_2), \ \gamma'(t_3):=\gamma_1'(t_0)$. The strategy is, for each step $t\in[t_0,t_3]$, to study the angles between  $\gamma'(t), V(\gamma(t)), \frac{\sigma_u(\gamma(t))}{\|\sigma_u(\gamma(t))\|}$ in the tangent space $T_{\gamma(t)}(S)$. We start with the first and the third vector:

For any $t$, define $X(t):= \frac{\sigma_u(\gamma(t))}{\|\sigma_u(\gamma(t))\|}$, $Y(t):= R_{90}(X(t))$ where $R_{90}$ denotes the 90-degree positive rotation on $T_{\gamma(t)}(S)$. For any $i\in \{1,2,3\}$, there exist smooth functions $a_i,b_i: [t_{i-1},t_i]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma_i'(t)= a_i(t)X(t)+b_i(t)Y(t)$, for all $t\in[t_{i-1},t_i]$. To capture the angle displacement along the $i^{\text{th}}$ edge, we define $\Delta \theta_i (t):= \int_{t_{i-1}}^t \left(a_i(\tau)b_i'(\tau)-b_i(\tau)a_i'(\tau)\right) d\tau$, for $t\in [t_{i-1},t_i]$. We combine to get the angle displacement starting from the time $t_0$:

\begin{equation}
\Delta \theta (t):= 
     \begin{cases}
       \Delta \theta_1 (t), &\quad t\in [t_0,t_1)\\
       \Delta \theta_1 (t_1)+ \alpha_1 +\Delta \theta_2 (t) , &\quad t\in [t_1,t_2) \\
       \Delta \theta_1 (t_1)+ \alpha_1 +\Delta \theta_2 (t_2)+\alpha_2+\Delta \theta_3 (t), &\quad t\in [t_2,t_3)\\
       \Delta  \theta_1 (t_1)+ \alpha_1 +\Delta \theta_2 (t_2)+\alpha_2+\Delta \theta_3 (t_3)+\alpha_3, &\quad t=t_3\\ 
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Finally, we need a starting angle: let $\theta_0\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $\gamma_1'(t_0)=\cos\theta_0\  X(t_0)+ \sin\theta_0\  Y(t_0)$. Now, our angle function is $\theta(t):= \theta_0+\Delta \theta (t)$. The proof of the following is standard in the literature (eg using Lemma 1 p.269, do Carmo): for all $t\in [t_0,t_3]$, $\gamma'(t)= \cos\theta(t)\  X(t)+ \sin\theta(t)\  Y(t)$. We will also use the following crucial fact: the whole angle displacement is $2\pi$, i.e., $\Delta \theta(t_3)=2\pi$. The proof of this is a part of proving GB, but it has nothing to do with Gaussian curvature. It is actually a consequence of Hopf's Umlaufsatz. For a proof, see Pressley p.339 and p. 344.

Now, we do the same thing for the angle between $V(\gamma(t))$, $\gamma'(t)$. For any $i\in \{1,2,3\}$, there exist smooth functions $c_i,d_i: [t_{i-1},t_i]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $V(\gamma_i(t))= c_i(t)\gamma_i'(t)+d_i(t)R_{90}(\gamma_i'(t))$, for all $t\in[t_{i-1},t_i]$. We define $\Delta \omega_i (t):= \int_{t_{i-1}}^t \left(c_i(\tau)d_i'(\tau)-c_i(\tau)d_i'(\tau)\right) d\tau$, for $t\in [t_{i-1},t_i]$. The angle displacement starting from the time $t_0$:

\begin{equation}
\Delta \omega (t):= 
     \begin{cases}
       \Delta \omega_1 (t), &\quad t\in [t_0,t_1)\\
       \Delta \omega_1 (t_1)- \alpha_1 +\Delta \omega_2 (t) , &\quad t\in [t_1,t_2) \\
       \Delta \omega_1 (t_1)-\alpha_1 +\Delta \omega_2 (t_2)-\alpha_2+\Delta \omega_3 (t), &\quad t\in [t_2,t_3)\\
       \Delta  \omega_1 (t_1)- \alpha_1 +\Delta \omega_2 (t_2)-\alpha_2+\Delta \omega_3 (t_3)-\alpha_3, &\quad t=t_3\\ 
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Observe that here the turning angles $\alpha_i$ must be subtracted. Finally, define the initial angle $\omega_0 \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $V(\gamma_1(t_0))=\cos \omega_0 \ \gamma_1'(t_0)+ \sin \omega_0\  R_{90}(\gamma_1'(t_0))$. We define $\omega(t)= \omega_0+\Delta \omega(t)$. As before, the following has standard proof: for all $t\in [t_0,t_3]$, $V(\gamma(t))=\cos \omega(t) \ \gamma'(t)+ \sin \omega(t)\  R_{90}(\gamma'(t))$.

Summing the angle functions $\theta$, $\omega$ we have an angle function between $V$ and $X$ (which is what we need to express the index). Formally, let $\phi:[t_0,t_3]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi:=\omega+\theta$. From the definitions of $\omega, \theta$, we can see that in $\phi$, the turning angles cancel-out, which makes $\phi$ continuous. Furthermore, $V(\gamma(t))=\cos \phi(t) \ X(t) + \sin \phi(t) \ Y(t) $. As it is explained in do Carmo's proof, if the triangle contains a singular point $q$, then $\Delta \phi:=\phi(t_3)-\phi(t_0)=2\pi I_q$ ($I_q$ is the index of $q$). Otherwise, $\Delta \phi=0$. Since $\phi=\omega+\theta$, we have $\Delta \phi=\Delta \theta(t_3)+ \Delta \omega(t_3)=2\pi+\Delta \omega(t_3)$. So, $$\Delta\omega_1 (t_1) +\Delta \omega_2 (t_2)+\Delta \omega_3 (t_3)- \alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3=\Delta \phi-2\pi$$

By summing over all triangles, using property 4 of the triangulation and the way $\Delta \omega_i$ are defined, we have that all terms $\Delta \omega_i(t_i)$ cancel. What is left is

$$\sum_T (2\pi -\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3 )=\sum_T \Delta \phi$$

The RHS is 2$\pi$ times the sum of indices of all the singular points. The LHS appears in the proof of Global GB and equals $2\pi \chi(S)$ (again the proof of this has nothing to do with Gaussian curvature, it's a combinatorial argument). We are done!

Comment: I did not read your proof, but one can find a direct proof for instance in Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology." There are other proofs, for instance, using Morse theory.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately,  I am not yet familiar with manifolds, but thanks for the reference.